# failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/dependecies/requirements.txt" not found: not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I am trying to build two Docker containers using docker-compose up but i keep getting the same error "failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/dependecies/requirements.txt" not found: not found"

```
Here is my folder organization:

-root
    -dependencies
        -requirements.txt
    -facadeback
        -Dockerfile
        .
        .
        .
    -docker-compose.yml
    -main.py
```

My Dockerfile content:

```
FROM python:3


RUN apt-get update -y; apt-get upgrade -y
RUN yes | apt install build-essential portaudio19-dev
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./dependecies/requirements.txt .
COPY . ./usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install torch
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "main"]
```

My docker-compose up content:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  
  python_app:
    build: ./facadeback/
    container_name: python-backend
    volumes:
      - ./facadeback:usr/src/app
    command: sh -c "sleep 10s"
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db

  mysql_db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql-bd
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
    volumes:
      - ./facadeadd/bd/:var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
```

Error log:

```
$ docker-compose up
[+] Building 2.5s (9/14)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                              0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                               0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3                       2.2s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 3.55kB                                               0.0s 
 => CANCELED [ 1/10] FROM docker.io/library/python:3@sha256:10fc14aa6ae69f69e4c9  0.2s 
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3@sha256:10fc14aa6ae69f69e4c953cffd9b096  0.0s 
 => => sha256:ee4e7a0f1c354d9996229a765d0785df2671252c1822ae1110 8.52kB / 8.52kB  0.0s 
 => => sha256:10fc14aa6ae69f69e4c953cffd9b0964843d8c163950491d21 2.14kB / 2.14kB  0.0s 
 => => sha256:3f53d697b58165ec41a16cdc5f9e29a32ab269568848886269 2.22kB / 2.22kB  0.0s 
 => CACHED [ 2/10] RUN apt-get update -y; apt-get upgrade -y                      0.0s 
 => CACHED [ 3/10] RUN yes | apt install build-essential portaudio19-dev          0.0s 
 => CACHED [ 4/10] RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip                        0.0s 
 => ERROR [ 5/10] COPY ./dependecies/requirements.txt .                           0.0s 
------
 > [ 5/10] COPY ./dependecies/requirements.txt .:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/dependecies/requirements.txt" not found: not found
```

Can anyone help me put this to work?? Thanks!!

Comment: Since you specify the `facadeback` directory as the build context, you can only `COPY` files from that directory tree into the image.  Do you need to move the requirements file into that directory, or specify the parent directory as the build context?  Also double-check the spelling of `dependencies` in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks, i moved the Dockerfile into the dependecies folder and it worked. Now i have another problem that i can´t solve.